# Как зайти на свой сайт django из интернета?

Tags: python, django

Запускаю **django-project**: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`

И не могу зайти на свой сайт через свой же **ip**: `http://178.176.113.51:80`

Интернет мне раздает iphone по usb, оператор "мегафон".

Как решить проблему? Все перегуглил. Ngrok не предлагать, мне нужно подключиться к своему ip.

Comment: А вы уверены, что мегафон роутит запросы к этому ip до вашего компьютера? Очень высока вероятность, что этот ip не только ваш, но ещё и сотен других пользователей мегафона

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, стало гораздо понятнее почему нужен белый ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы можно было зайти на ip-адрес из внешнего интернета, этот ip-адрес должен быть "белым". Но провайдеры интернета обычным пользователям раздают "серые" адреса.

Соответственно, нужно либо отдельно за дополнительную плату арендовать у провайдера "белый" адрес, либо всё-таки использовать хостинг.

Хостинг, имхо, проще.

Answer (score 0):

Если я тебя правильно понял, чтобы зайти на него из интернета, можешь развернуть его на [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com)

Если не правильно, то запустив его на локальном сервере будет написано, как на него зайти, но доступ будет только с локального сервера[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: python manage.py runserver запускает сервер локально, да, тут все работает. А мне нужно подключиться к своему проекту извне, но без использования хостингов. Хочу зайти на него по своему адресу http://178.176.113.51:80, как это сделать? python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 не помогает.